# Multiple controls with the same ID were found

Tags: asp.net

I have following asp.net code but it gives error when I change dropdown selected index:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drp" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_SelectedIndexChanged">
          <asp:ListItem Text="ABC" Value="ABC"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="DEF" Value="DEF"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="drp" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
      </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now made one function for create textbox and get textbox value into lable as following way

```
protected void drp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
  if (drp.SelectedIndex != 0)
  {
    ViewState["controls"] = true;
    CreateTextbox(drp.SelectedIndex);
  }

}

private void CreateTextbox(int Number)
{
  try
  {
    TextBox txtTextbox;
    Label lbltxtTextbox;
    for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
    {
      txtTextbox = new TextBox();
      txtTextbox.ID = "txtbox" + i;
      lbltxtTextbox = new Label();
      lbltxtTextbox.ID = "lbltxtbox" + i;
      pnl.Controls.Add(txtTextbox);
      pnl.Controls.Add(lbltxtTextbox);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}

private void GetTextboxvalue(int Number)
{
  try
  {
    TextBox txtTextbox;
    Label lbltxtTextbox;
    for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
    {
      txtTextbox = (TextBox)pnl.FindControl("txtbox" + i);
      lbltxtTextbox = (Label)pnl.FindControl("lbltxtbox" + i);
      lbltxtTextbox.Text = txtTextbox.Text;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GetTextboxvalue(drp.SelectedIndex);
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  if (ViewState["controls"] != null)
    if (drp.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
      CreateTextbox(drp.SelectedIndex);
    }



}
```

error is:

```
Multiple controls with the same ID 'txtbox0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.
```

Comment: View the html source from your browser which will help you to find all the rendered controls.

Comment: if you change your dropdown list twice to the same item you make the same textboxe twice and so you end up with the same ids.

Comment: Depending on what you exactly want to do, maybe you should call pnl.Controls.Clear() as first statement of your try block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**GUID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)

Change the following line

```
txtTextbox.ID = "txtbox" + sequentialId;
```

to below line

```
txtTextbox.ID = "txtbox" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

---

You can follow the same approach in remaining places.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following fix for the error you got.

When `drp_SelectedIndexChanged` is fired on `SelectedIndexChanged` and it is `not zero index` you get the error "Multiple controls with the same ID 'txtbox0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs." when index 1 is selected for more then one times.

Change

```
if (drp.SelectedIndex != 0) statement
```

To

```
if (drp.SelectedIndex != 0 && ViewState["controls"] != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when any control ID is missing or more than one control have the same ID assigned. to get rid of this error, make the ID values of each control unique.

see the example below, the loop increment value j is appended dynamically to the id value to make the id value increment

pnl.ID = "pnltype" + j.ToString();

```
for (int j = 0; j < dtRtype.Rows.Count; j++)
{        
  pnl = new Panel();
  pnl.Width = panelWidth;
  pnl.Height = panelHeight;
  pnl.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
  pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
  pnl.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
  pnl.BorderWidth = 2;
  pnl.Style["position"] = "absolute";
  pnl.Style["bottom"] = bottom.ToString() + "px";
  pnl.Style["left"] = left.ToString() + "px";
  pnl.ID = "pnltype" + j.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the CreateTextBox procedure as follows:

```
private void CreateTextbox(int Number)
{
  pnl.Controls.Clear();
```

Answer (score -1):

The specific reason you're getting this error is you are calling `CreateTextbox()` on `SelectedIndexChanged` when the textboxes have already been created on `Page_Load`.

@Pankaj's answer works great, but I thought I would add another solution, taking in consideration the reason for the error.

I understand you need `CreateTextBox()` to be called on `Page_Load` for the initial view, so...

### SOLUTION

If you just add `pnl.Controls.Clear()` in your `CreateTextBox()` method before creating the textboxes again, that would resolve your issue. So it would look like this:

```
private void CreateTextbox(int Number)
{
  try
  {
    TextBox txtTextbox;
    Label lbltxtTextbox;
    for (int i = 0; i < Number; i++)
    {
      txtTextbox = new TextBox();
      txtTextbox.ID = "txtbox" + i;
      lbltxtTextbox = new Label();
      lbltxtTextbox.ID = "lbltxtbox" + i;
      //Clear the controls before adding them again.
      pnl.Controls.Clear();
      pnl.Controls.Add(txtTextbox);
      pnl.Controls.Add(lbltxtTextbox);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

One reason to consider this method over creating random unique ID's is: sometimes you need to be able to predict the name of the control from the code behind so you're able to retrieve a value, as I've had occasion.

Anyway, I thought I'd contribute, if perhaps someone needed a different approach. =)

Comment: @Downvoter I don't see how my answer fits the criteria for a bad or inapplicable post. Do you have any feedback as to the reason for the downvote? Are there any issues with my approach in this solution?